# How do I fill a histogram in Matlab if one gets extremely many different copies of the vector to be histogramed?

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram

I was trying to collect statistics of a 6D vector and plot a 1D histogram for each coordinate. I get 729000000 different copies of this vector (each 6 dimensional). For this I create an array of zeros of size 729000000x6 before I get any of the actual W's and this seems to be a problem in matlab since it says:

```
Error using zeros
Requested 729000000x6 (32.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays
greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array
size limit or preference panel for more information.
```

The reason I did this at first was because it was easy to fill `W_history` and then just feed it to the histogram plotter:

```
histogram(W_history(:,d),nbins,'Normalization','probability')
```

however filling `W_history` seemed impossible for high number of copies of W. Is there a way to do this in matlab automatically? It feels that there should be and didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

I am sure I could potentially create for each coordinate some array of counters where I count how many times a specific value of the coordinate `W` falls. However, implementing that and having the checks for in which bin each one should fall seemed inefficient or even unnecessary. Is this really the only solution or what do matlab experts people recommend? Is this re-inventing the wheel? Seems also inefficient if I implement it myself?

---

Also, I thought I could manually have matlab put thing in memory then bring them back etc (as in store `W_history` in disk as it fills and then put more back in disk as it fills and eventually somehow plug it in to the histogram plotter), that seemed overwork. I hope I can avoid a solution like this one. It feels a wrong solution since it should be "easy" and high level to use matlab and going down to disk and memory doesn't seem to me what matlab is intended.

---

Currently through the comment that was given the best solution that I have so far is using `histcounts` as follow:

```
for i=2:iter+1
    %
    W = get_new_W(W)
    %
    [W_hist_counts_current, edges2] = histcounts(W,edges);
    W_hist_counts = W_hist_counts + W_hist_counts_current;
end
```

however, after this it seems difficult to convert `W_hist_counts` to pdf/probability or other values since it seems they have to be processed manually. Is there no official way to do this processing without the user having to implement the normalizations again?

Comment: you could do this in batches, each time use `histc` to get histogram counts for a given batch, and sum all the batches. You won't need too many iterations. Just make sure you use the same bins (read the doc for `histc`)

Comment: @ItamarKatz nice! didn't know that existed. Now just need to find how to plot a histogram given the output of `histcounts`.

Comment: @ItamarKatz do you know to actually plot the things `histcounts` outputs? It seems to be a bit trickier than I thought *and it seems bar isn't the suggest way to do it?)

Comment: if you use `[N,edges] = histcounts(X,edges)`, why not just `plot(edges,N,'.')`? Or any similar plot, that is you might want to plot bin centers and not edges. Also you can normalize `N=N/sum(N)`.