# What is the official Matlab way to plot the values of histcounts into a histogram with any normalization option?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

Assume that I have an array of counts (ideally returned by `histcounts`). Is there an official Matlab way to plot such a histogram with all [the standard normalization options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) available?

It seems that the best suggestion I have is to get the counts from `histcounts` and then plot them with `bar`. Something like:

```
edges = linspace(0,bound,nbins);
hist_c = histcounts(X,nbins);
bar(edges(1:nbins-1),hist_c);
```

unfortunately as far as I know it seems that using bar is really not recommended according to [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91944-how-can-i-combine-the-options-histc-and-stack-in-a-bar-plot-in-matlab-7-4-r2007a#answer_101295). Probably because as its obvious from the code, it seems that it moves a lot of implementation details into user code (like produces edges array manually when only needing `nbins` or having to know if to use `1:nbins-1` vs `2:nbins`).

Furthermore, which I believe is the worst, is that it leave the user to have to implement the normalization options on its own. One may point out that `histcounts` can do the normalization options for you, however, it can only do them given the data matrix `X`. If one had an extremely large matrix `X`, then one would be in trouble because producing the histogram counts of `X` could be done on the fly (as done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025103/how-do-i-fill-a-histogram-in-matlab-if-one-gets-extremely-many-different-copies#comment73192535_43025103)) but the other normalization options could not be easily be done on the fly. One practice the user could try to implement each normalization option as described by the equations in the documentation but it seems extremely inefficient to have users implement this by hand. Is there a way to get access to the code that actually performs this normalization?

In reality what my question is going for is, is there an official matlab way to produce histogram having **only the histogram counts**? In particular hiding all the implementation details of producing the counts, normalization, binning, edges, etc?

The ideal code in my mind should look like this to the user:

```
histogram_counts  = get_hist_count(X)
plot_histogram(histogram_counts,'Normalization',normalization)
```

and produces the desired histogram plot.

---

Related question:

- https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/332178-how-does-one-plot-a-histogram-from-the-histogram-counts
- https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/275278-what-is-the-recommended-practice-for-plotting-the-outputs-of-histcounts
- https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91944-how-can-i-combine-the-options-histc-and-stack-in-a-bar-plot-in-matlab-7-4-r2007a#answer_101295

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24178929/7659682

Comment: I don't see anything in the link that suggests that `bar` is not recommended. I see a reference from 2009 that use of the `histc` option is undocumented and thus may be removed at any time, but the current documentation [clearly includes this option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#input_argument_d0e63117).